# Chat between server and client

Tags: sockets

I want to create a chat program between a server and a client, I want the client or server to be able to send message to the other end at anytime without waiting for example:

```
Client: hi
Server: hi
Server: I'm the server.
Server: How are you?
Client: Good.
```

In this example the Server doesn't wait for the Client to reply and sends another message at anytime.

Should I use the function `select`?, If so how should I determine the timeout and is the timeout value is the solution for busy waiting?

Is `select` function is the best approach for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Language? Platform? Error? Question?

Answer (score 1):

Using `select` seems like the right approach, especially if you want the program to work on Windows. This will allow you to block the process and wait for a message from multiple clients simultaneously.

In general you should set the timeout to `NULL` so that the server will block indefinitely for a request from a client. The timeout is only useful if you want to additionally wake up the server at regular intervals for other reasons.

If you are targetting Unices (like Linux) it is easier and more efficient to use [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll). This does basically the same thing but the interface is easier to work with. `select` becomes quite awkward to use if the file descriptor numbers become larger than 1024, which is a problem if you ever expect your server to handle large numbers of clients.

If you are targeting Linux specifically and don't care about portability you can even use [epoll](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) which has even more performance advantages and is arguably easier to use.

If you are only targeting Windows, you can [create event objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx) for each of the sockets and then use [WaitForMultipleObjectsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028(v=vs.85).aspx) to wait for data from any of them. This provides similar functionality to `poll` but the API is quite involved.